# Calculating the number of common occurrences ,and values in a categorical variable ​for each observation in R studio

Tags: r

My **DataFrame** consists of two columns, the first is `id` the second is `Value.1`.
I want to create a table with 4 columns:

1. `id`
2. amount of times each `id` occurs in the table
3. which value (in Value 1) occurs the most for each `id`
4. how many times.

The output should be a table consists the four sections above.

my input:

**Data.**

```
Value.1        id
a              235
a              235
b              256
b              258
c              235
c              222
c              258
a              256
c              258
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code does what the question asks for.

1. Get the counts (`times`) by groups of `id` and `Value.1`
2. Group by `id`, the final grouping criterion
3. Get the maximum of the counts
4. Create a string of all `Value.1` equal to the maximum of `times`
5. Sum the `times`

This is implemented as a pipe.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  count(id, Value.1, name = "times") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Times.of.Common.value.1 = max(times),
            Common.value.1 = paste(Value.1[times == Times.of.Common.value.1], collapse = ","),
            times = sum(times))
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#     id Times.of.Common.value.1 Common.value.1 times
#  <int>                   <int> <chr>          <int>
#1   222                       1 c                  1
#2   235                       2 a                  3
#3   256                       1 a,b                2
#4   258                       2 c                  3
```

## Edit.

Following OP's comments here is the output of `count`.

```
df1 %>%
  count(id, Value.1, name = "times")
## A tibble: 7 x 3
#     id Value.1 times
#  <int> <fct>   <int>
#1   222 c           1
#2   235 a           2
#3   235 c           1
#4   256 a           1
#5   256 b           1
#6   258 b           1
#7   258 c           2
```

## Data.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Value.1        id
a              235
a              235
b              256
b              258
c              235
c              222
c              258
a              256
c              258
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: i made data frame of these 2 columns. did what yo wrote and actually get "object times not found".

Comment: @נעמהגבריאל Does your column `Value.1` has spaces in its name? Check also upper/lower case, R is case sensitive.

Comment: what do you expect from the line  df1 %>%count(id, Value.1, name = "times") to be? i mean what the output should be?

Comment: @נעמהגבריאל That instruction counts the number of rows by groups of both `id` and `Value.1` and gives the count column the name `times`. See now. See also its [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html). And I `ungroup` after, which is unnecessary, will edit to remove that code line.